# Angulare Directive only one instance works, when i use 2 sepate directives

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have a directive for `arrow up` and `arrow down` needs. when i copy and page one of the instance of directive only the second one works but not the first one.

how to solve this? please focus on second section "green" colored section on first element and do the `up and down` arrow movement.

directive.ts:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  AfterViewInit,
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocuser]',
})
export class AutoFocusDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  focusableArray = [];
  parent = null;
  count = 0;
  currentFocus: HTMLElement;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event']) onKeyup = ($event) => {
    if ($event.code === 'ArrowDown') {
      if (this.count >= this.focusableArray.length - 1) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.focusableArray[this.count].focus();
        return;
      }
      this.count++;
      this.focusableArray[this.count].focus();
    }
    if ($event.code === 'ArrowUp') {
      if (this.count == 0) {
        this.count = this.focusableArray.length - 1;
        this.focusableArray[this.count].focus();
        return;
      }
      this.count--;
      this.focusableArray[this.count].focus();
    }
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.parent = this.el.nativeElement;
    this.focusableArray = Array.from(
      this.parent.querySelectorAll(`[data-focus=true]`)
    );
    if (this.focusableArray.length) {
      this.currentFocus = this.focusableArray[this.count];
      this.currentFocus.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaauhp?file=src/app/directives/autoFocusable.directive.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, both instances work. One after another. Here

```
  @HostListener('document:keyup', ['$event']) onKeyup = ($event) => {
```

you're listening to the keyup event on the whole document. Every instance of `AutoFocusDirective` catches it, all handlers are executed, presumably in the order of the directives' initialization (probably). The first one assigns focus somewhere (you even see a flash of that). Then the second one does the same, stealing the focus.

One solution would be to instead of listening on `document:keyup`, listen on `keyup`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because only one element in a page can be focused. You must put both `section` parts in another element and give the `appFocuser` directive to that element.

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jvbr88)